# monitor vps bandwidth usage

Tags: linux, iptables, vps, network-monitoring

I have a vps guest whose ip is 192.168.1.20. I add the following lines to iptables,

`# iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.20`

`# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.20`

Then I run this line to monitor the usage

`# iptables -L FORWARD -v -x | grep '192.168.1.20'`

But the value of the result is always 0.

Comment: How did you go with this?

Comment: I'm still figuring it out. I moved the two lines to the top of FORWARD  CHAIN. But I still get nothing when monitoring the usage. I tested with wget, yum update commands inside guest os. I guess the packages are filtered through INPUT/OUTPUT chains?

Comment: Would love to know if you got any further with this.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your rules it's hard to say 100% but it could be that earlier rules in iptables are acting like a catch all, and traffic isn't getting to the forward rules you've shown in your question (this would explain why you're not seeing any data).

### As per MadHatter:

> Put your two audit rules first, and they should be fine.

### Another approach:

Consider using the -j option, which is explained here:
http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html

> -j, --jump target This specifies the target of the rule; i.e., what to do if the packet matches it. The target can be a user-defined chain
>   (other than the one this rule is in), one of the special builtin
>   targets which decide the fate of the packet immediately, or an
>   extension (see EXTENSIONS below). If this option is omitted in a rule
>   (and -g is not used), then matching the rule will have no effect on
>   the packet's fate, but the counters on the rule will be incremented.

This might serve as a good starting point for you:

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/305767-bandwidth-monitoring-with-iptables

> After a rule is matched, the -j option invokes a jump to one of the
>   custom chains.

Comment: The first part of Drew's answer is probably the right one: iptables works on first-dispositive-match wins, which means that chain processing stops for any given packet after a match with a dispositive target (ACCEPT, REJECT, etc.) is found.  Put your two audit rules first, and they should be fine.  But I disagree strongly with the second part of his answer; rules without targets are an excellent and safe way of accumulating audit data.